# Manually compile and run multiple packages using javac/java

Tags: java, javac

Let's say I have the following folder structure:

\src\com\proj\pp1\stuff where `com.proj.pp1` and `com.proj.pp1.stuff` are the two packages I have:

```
    -src
      -com
        -proj
          -pp1
             tester.java
             -stuff
                some other .java's
```

Being the main function in tester.java, and using the classes declared in /stuff.

In `tester.java` I declare the imports that way:

```
package com.proj.pp1;    
import com.proj.pp1.*;
```

And in all the files declared under stuff:

```
package com.proj.pp1.stuff;
```

without any imports.

I'm able to get the .class's doing the following, being in `/pp1` folder:

```
javac tester.java stuff/*.java
```

But when I try to run the tester class:

```
java tester
```

It gives me the error output:
*Could not find or load main class tester*
and the very same thing if I try `java com.proj.pp1.tester`

What do you think could be the actual problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`javac` takes *files* as arguments, so it should be

```
cd src
javac com/proj/pp1/tester.java
```

That should compile `tester.java` and all related classes.

and `java` takes the main *class* as argument, so to run it you do:

```
java com.proj.pp1.tester
```

(When you invoke `java com.proj.pp1.tester` make sure `com/proj/pp1/tester.class` exists.)

You might want to read up on `-d` option for `javac` to avoid putting your classes in the source directory.

Comment: Oh that totally worked. So should I always tell javac the full path (the one that matches with the package name)?

Comment: Yes. You should always sit in the root of the source tree when invoking javac (and in the root of the bin directory when invoking java).

Answer (score 0):

```
javac -d bin src/*.java src/stuff/*.java
java -classpath bin src.Main
```