# Use javac only sitting in the root of the source tree? What does it mean?

Tags: java

I have a professor who always insists on

> "sitting in the root of the source tree when invoking `javac` (and in the root of the directory when invoking `java`)".

Although, for the basic programs I have done, I have never found the need of doing that.

So, what is the need of doing it?

Comment: Both `javac` and `java` will expect to find source and class files laid out according to package structure.

Comment: You mean something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/28527495/1977152

Comment: Yes, exactly. There are ways of getting around all this, but it's generally best to do as your professor is recommending here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that if you have a package, `foo`, and a class or classes in that package:

```
package foo;
class Nifty {
    // ...
}
```

...and your source tree looks like (and it mostly has to):

```
+ source
  + foo
    + Nifty.java
```

`javac` will expect to be in the `source` directory when you're compiling, not in the `foo` directory. It's just how `javac` is.

`java` will expect that the classpath will include `source` (not `foo`), and like `javac` work relative to that (looking in `foo` for the classes in the package `foo`).

Comment: So the correct way to use javac would be like `javac foo/Nifty.java` and that of java would be `java foo.Nifty` right?

Comment: @Bateman: Exactly right (for \*nix systems); on Windows it would be `javac foo\Nifty.java`. (Although it wouldn't surprise me if it worked both ways.)